# How to stop Xpath pagination loop at empty webpage?

Tags: selenium, xpath, pagination, scrapy

I have build a spider that scrapes a certain website and it works fine, I used the scrapy for it. The spider scraped all the 430 webpages that I wanted to scrape, by following the 'next page' pagination link. The problem is that the site/scraper also directs to the 431th page, which is empty. And so on. Therefore, the scraper won't stop scraping!

Can anybody help me to stop the webscraper after all the relevant 430 pages are scraped?? The html code within the last, relevant page is: [image: HTML code]

My code is:

```
next_page = response.xpath('//a[@id="nextWebshopsPage"]').attrib['href']
    if next_page is not None:
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify in predicate that button *should not be disabled*:

```
'//a[@id="nextWebshopsPage" and not(@disabled)]'
```